# If a page titles equals a specific title, display content in NopCommerce

Tags: c#, if-statement, nopcommerce

I'm new to **NopCommerce**,

Trying to write some code to display a specific image, for a `specific product category`.

For instance, once a **user clicks** on `books a image of a book` will display, and so on.

```
@{
if (Model.SubCategories.Name.ToString().Equals("Books")){
    <div class="image">
        <img src="~/image/book.png" />
    </div>
}
```

}

Comment: What is your question friend? and what have you tried so far (paste some code).

Comment: so i want to be able to add image to a specific category in nop commerce, i think a simple if statement is needed to state this category will then display this image. E.g. books category displays a image of a book

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a new category template copying the default `CategoryTemplate.ProductsInGridOrLines` and make your changed on it.

You will find the default template under `/Views/Catalog folder`, copy it and change the name.

Next configure the commerce so the system could use this new category template, depending of the version of nopcommerce this can be done in two diferent ways:

- For **old versions** you will need to access your database and insert a row in the CategoryTemplate table.
- For **new versions** you can do it under `System->Templates->Categories`

Next you can select this template in a dropdown when you configure your category and this template will be used instead of the default